# Writing bmp file in C gives wrong result

Tags: c, bmp

I'm trying to write a function that reads a bmp file and then makes a copy of it. I'm reading the image header to a struct as usual, and copying the pixel values to RGB matrices.

The function that I'm building to write the BMP file gives the right image width/height and size, but the image is all black and when the pixel values are all wrong (I'm comparing it to the original bmp image by making a hex dump with `xxd`).

Here is the function to write a BMP file:

```
void writeBMP(BMPFILEHEADER *headerData,BMPINFOHEADER *headerInfo, int values[headerInfo->width*headerInfo->height]) {

        FILE *out;
        out = fopen("example.bmp", "wb");
        fwrite(headerData, sizeof(char), sizeof(BMPFILEHEADER), out);
        fseek(out, 14, SEEK_SET);
        fwrite(headerInfo, sizeof(char), sizeof(BMPINFOHEADER), out);
        fseek(out, 54, SEEK_SET);
        fwrite(values, sizeof(char), headerInfo->imagesize, out);
        fclose(out);
    }
```

I've checked `values` (that's where I've stored pixel data) using printf and the pixel values match with the original image pixels. But looks like the line `fwrite(values, sizeof(char), headerInfo->imagesize, out)` is writing the wrong data to the file.

EDIT: I'm adding other details about the code

Function to read pixel data:

```
RGBmatrix readPixels(char *fileName, BMPFILEHEADER *header, BMPINFOHEADER *info) {
    FILE *fp;
    int **matR, **matG, **matB;
    int RGBvalues[info->width][info->height];

    RGBmatrix values;

    matR = allocateRGB(matR, info->width, info->height);
    matG = allocateRGB(matG, info->width, info->height);
    matB = allocateRGB(matB, info->width, info->height);

    fp = fopen(fileName, "rb");
    if(fp==NULL) {
        printf("Can't open file\n");
    }

    fseek(fp, header->offset, SEEK_SET);

    for(int i = 0; i<info->width; i++) {
        for(int j=0; j<info->height;j++) {
            fread(&RGBvalues[i][j], 3, 1, fp);
        }
    }

    for(int i=0; i<info->width; i++) {
        for(int j=0; j<info->height; j++) {
            matB[i][j] =  RGBvalues[i][j] & 0xff;
            matG[i][j] = (RGBvalues[i][j]>>8) & 0xff;
            matR[i][j] = (RGBvalues[i][j]>>16) & 0xff; 
        }
    }

    values.R = matR;
    values.G = matG;
    values.B = matB;

    return values;
}
```

Structs to hold BMP data:

```
typedef struct RGBmatrix {
    int **R, **G, **B;
}RGBmatrix;

typedef struct BMPFILEHEADER {
    short int magicNumber;
    int bmpfSize;
    short int reserved1;
    short int reserverd2;
    int offset;
}BMPFILEHEADER;

typedef struct BMPINFOHEADER {
    unsigned int size;
    int width, height;
    unsigned short int planes;
    unsigned short int bits;
    unsigned int compression;
    unsigned int imagesize;
    int xresolution, yresolution;
    unsigned int ncolours;
    unsigned int importantcolours;
}BMPINFOHEADER;
```

My main function:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    BMPFILEHEADER headerData;
    BMPINFOHEADER headerInfo;
    FILE *fp;
    char fileName[20];

    strcpy(fileName, argv[1]); // command line argument to bmp file

    readBMPHeader(fileName, &headerData, &headerInfo); // read header data
    RGBmatrix values = readPixels(fileName, &headerData, &headerInfo); // read pixels

    int rgbModifiedValues[headerInfo.width*headerInfo.height];

    // do stuff with RGB values and store them into rgbModified Values

    writeBMP(&headerData, &headerInfo, rgbModifiedValues);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please provide a *complete* example.

Comment: If you have compared the file dumps can't you find where it goes wrong? Don't forget that the number of bytes in each raster line must be a multiple of 4 (stride), so padding may be needed.

Comment: @WeatherVane The hex dump from the copied bmp looks almost random in comparision with the original bmp. It's a 24 bit image, and I've checked the values that the 'writeBMP' function is receiving, and they match with the correct values. I think I'm messing with the fwrite() part, but I'm not sure how

Comment: @AndrewHenle I've updated the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I expect that you're writing a 256-color (8 bit) BMP file.

If that is so, it is possible that by using `int` values, you're writing incorrect entries in the file:

```
  these are not 8-bit in size
  |
  v
  int values[headerInfo->width*headerInfo->height])


  fwrite(values, sizeof(char), headerInfo->imagesize, out);
                 ^
                 |
                 but here you seem to treat them as if they are
```

You should be using `unsigned char` or `uint8_t` if available.

If I am correct then you should be seeing now an image which is mostly black (or mostly one color), with vertical or diagonal stripes, and the hex dump should show nonzero values interleaved with one or three zeroes; the nonzero values being themselves correct:

```
Expected pixel values
12  17  4B

Integer values in memory, read as bytes:

12 0 0 0 17 0 0 0 4B 0 0 0
```

Comment: Hi! It's actually a 24bit BMP. I've updated the question, adding more details on the code that I'm using.

Comment: If it is a 24 bit image, then each pixel requires exactly three bytes (R, G and B component). You are writing the wrong information. You can see that when you **read** those values, you do much more than just reading them into an int** array (the `fread(&RGBvalues[i][j], 3, 1, fp);` code in a double loop). So why would writing directly such an array result in a correct file?

Comment: also note that scanlines are padded with 0-3 bytes, so that scanlinesize is divisible with 4